# Calculate Percentile in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

This is my below list. I am trying to calculate 95% of calls came back in how many millseconds.

```
Milliseconds   Number of Calls
    45         14
    46         33
    47         40
    48         41
    49         83
    50         114
    51         124
    52         82
    53         89
    54         99
    55         82
    56         72
    57         80
    58         101
    59         73
    60         74
    61         81
    62         64
    63         70
    64         61
```

What does above data means is-

```
14 calls came back in 45 milliseconds
33 calls came back in 46 milliseconds
40 calls came back in 47 milliseconds
etc etc
```

Now I am supposed to find out `95% percentile` from the above data. Meaning 95% of time, calls came back in this milliseconds.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Excel Sheet? Thanks for the help

I am using Excel 2010. I have copied both the columns in my Excel Sheet as it is to calculate the percentage.

**Update:-**

With the below list, I am getting `95 percentil`e as 66. So that means 95% of time, calls came back in `66 milliseconds` which is not right I guess. It looks to me 95% of time, calls came back in ~4ms.

```
Milliseconds    Number of calls
    0           11
    1           259
    2           504
    3           293
    4           38
    5           15
    6           1
    7           4
    8           1
    9           1
    10          1
    11          2
    23          1
    30          1
    39          1
    147         1
```

I am using this formula-

```
=PERCENTILE(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(B$2:B$21))))<=B$2:B$21,A$2:A$21),0.95)
```

Comment: I don't think you are using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER correctly - place the formula in a cell and press F2 key to select formula - then hold down `CTRL` and `SHIFT` while pressing `ENTER`. If done correctly you will get curly braces like { and } around the formula....and the correct result - note that the LOOKU formula should get the same result.....but doesn't need CSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extra column would simplify the calculations but you can calculate without if you want......

Assuming milliseconds in A2:A21 and number of calls in B2:B21 you can use this array formula

`=PERCENTILE(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(B$2:B$21))))<=B$2:B$21,A$2:A$21),0.95)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or this non-array version

`=LOOKUP(SUM(B$2:B$21)*0.95,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B$1,0,0,ROW(B$2:B$21)-ROW(B$2)+1)),A$2:A$21)`

I get a result of 63 with both - change to 0.75 (75th percentile) and you get 59

Comment: What does this line means in your answer? `I get a result of 63 with both - change to 0.75 (75th percentile) and you get 59`. When I did your process, I got `63.05`. So why you added 0.75 and how you got 59?

Comment: Aaah.. you meant 75th percentile is 59. Right?

Comment: So that means 95 percentage of time, calls came back in 63 ms? Right? And 75% percent of time, calls came back in 59 ms?

Comment: And one more thing what does ctrl + shift + enter do here? When i am pressing enter, I am getting different result and when I am pressing ctrl + shift + enter, I am getting different result

Comment: `ctrl` `shift` and `enter` are required to enter array formulas.

Comment: barry houdini. Can you take a look into my comment? Whatever I said is right?

Comment: Hello TechGeeky, yes, sorry I've been busy - yes you were right with comment 3 - as Skip Intro says, array formulas need to be enter with a key combination of CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - if you do that correctly you get curly braces like { and } around the formula......although the LOOKUP version can be entered normally - do the results look OK to you?

Comment: @barryhoudini, I updated my question with more details. It looks like your formula is not getting right results. Can you take a look and let me know if I did something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER correctly - place the formula in a cell and press F2 key to select formula - then hold down `CTRL` and `SHIFT` while pressing `ENTER`. If done correctly you will get curly braces like { and } around the formula....and the correct result - note that the LOOKU formula should get the same result.....but doesn't need CSE

Answer (score 1):

Set up a new column which is "Number of Calls At or Below Time", and have it calculate the sum of the current row's number of calls, plus all numbers of calls in higher rows (lower times). Then, set up a column next to that called "Percentile", and calculate that by dividing "Number of Calls at or Below Time" by the total number of calls received. Whatever is the first row to show a percentile higher than 95% is the one which contains the 95th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

Get the standard deviation of the time in milliseconds field, and use that to (95% ~ 2 x std) count the number of calls below ~2 standard deviations?

Comment: I got confused. Can you provide me step by step or walk me through the steps how to do that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you use macros? or add another column?

Comment: That answer was assuming the distribution is gaussian, So it might be wrong. But you can just add another count column next to the 'Number of calls' column and then use that to find where you hit the 95th percentile.

Comment: I am new to Excel thing. So don't what does macros means here.

Comment: ok, so add another column besides the original column, to sum all the calls upto that point. Then see where it exceeds 95% of total # of calls. Is that workable?

Comment: Yeah. But that another columns will be what? Just the mixture of my two columns right? Meaning third column will have 45 14 times right? And other milliseconds like that. And then calculate the 95 percentile like this?

Comment: Ex. document (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiY2VlImJcjfdDZieWF2bGFZcVFsQmI3MF9RSXk4d1E&usp=sharing)

Comment: Add your data to the google doc I sent. Maybe we can do it there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27056/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-xcorat)