# How to calculate 95th percentile in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, percentile

I am trying to calculate how many calls came back in 95 percentile of time. Below is my Result Set. I am working with `Excel 2010`

```
Milliseconds    Number
0               1702
1               15036
2               14262
3               13190
4               9137
5               5635
6               3742
7               2628
8               1899
9               1298
10              963
11              727
12              503
13              415
14              311
15              235
16              204
17              140
18              109
19              83
20              72
21              55
22              52
23              35
24              33
25              25
26              15
27              18
28              14
29              15
30              13
31              19
32              23
33              19
34              21
35              20
36              25
37              26
38              13
39              12
40              10
41              17
42              6
43              7
44              8
45              4
46              7
47              9
48              11
49              12
50              9
51              9
52              9
53              8
54              10
55              10
56              11
57              3
58              7
59              7
60              2
61              5
62              7
63              5
64              5
65              2
66              3
67              2
68              1
70              1
71              2
72              1
73              4
74              1
75              1
76              1
77              3
80              1
81              1
85              1
87              2
93              1
96              1
100             1
107             1
112             1
116             1
125             1
190             1
356             1
450             1
492             1
497             1
554             1
957             1
```

Just some background what does above information means-

```
1702 calls came back in 0 milliseconds
15036 calls came back in 1 milliseconds
14262 calls came back in 2 milliseconds
etc etc
```

So to calculate the 95th percentile from the above data, I am using this formula in excel 2010-

`=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&MAX(H$2:H$96))))<=H$2:H$96,A$2:A$96),0.95)`

Can anyone help me whether the way I am doing in Excel 2010 is right or not?

I am getting 95th percentile as 10 by using the above scenario.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's essentially the same question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671408/calculate-percentile-in-excel-2010/15671753#15671753) and the formula I suggested. As per my last comments in that question - that formula should work OK as long as you use `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` correctly. I get 10 as the answer for this example using that formula.

I think you can verify manually that that is indeed the correct answer. If you have a running total in an adjacent column then you can see where the 95th percentile is reached......

Comment: Thanks a lot barry for the suggestion. I just wanted to make sure, I am not missing anything. As I read some article on the internet that we should use PERCENTILE.EXC method as compared to PERCENTILE function in Excel 2010 so wanted to confirm that, I am not doing anything wrong. Let me know your thoughts on that as well. And secondly, if I need to calculate Average from the above datasets how can I do that?

Comment: For the average milliseconds per call you can use SUMPRODUCT to get the total milliseconds and then divide by the number of calls, i.e `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A96,H2:H96)/SUM(H2:H96)`

Comment: The difference between PERCENTILE and PERCENTILE.EXC is that the former calculates the rank as K*(N-1)+1 while the latter uses K*(N+1). For your purposes where N = 72983 in above example and where you have very large numbers of repeated values it's very unlikely to make a difference which one you use (note PERCENTILE.INC = PERCENTILE)